# Error: %pre(MariaDB-server-10.5.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Tags: mysql, apache, mariadb, centos7, cyber-panel

I am new for VPS, recently I have restored my cPanel backup on my VPS using CyberPanel but when I am updating my VPS using the command:
**yum update -y**
Then I have seen this error:
error: %pre(MariaDB-server-10.5.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package MariaDB-server-10.5.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64
error: MariaDB-server-10.5.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64: install failed
MariaDB-server-10.1.46-1.el7.centos.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
Verifying  : MariaDB-server-10.1.46-1.el7.centos.x86_64
Failed:
MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.46-1.el7.centos

**While my all restored domains works fine and are live at present.**
How can I fix it?
**Note: My all restored domains works fine and are live at present.**
Regards,

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the update command is to update all applications, correct? It could be that it can't update MariaDB to the latest one because the MariaDB service is running while the its tying to update?

Comment: Yes, the update command is to update all applications. Is this error affect my websites anyway?

Comment: I don't think it will affect your website. It's just telling you it can't update due to the app still in use. Therefore, it doesn't successfully uninstall the old version and install the new version. I'm positive that it doesn't do any damage to your website since you said the website works fine and all. If your website doesn't work immediately after the error message, that would've been a clear sign.